# for loop range syntax

Tags: matlab, octave

I spent a couple of hours debugging a problem that I would have thought would have been a syntax error.

```
a = zeros(3);
for i=1:1size(a,2) % note the missing colon between 1 and size(a,2)
    i
end
```

The following only displays

```
ans = 3
1
```

Essentially, it seems Matlab/Octave parses the above as:

```
for i=1:1
    size(a,2)
    i
end
```

Note however that

```
i=1:1size(a,2)
```

produces a syntax error.  Is there a good reason that Matlab/Octave has this for loop syntax?  Is there something that it's supposed to make easier?  Just curious if anyone else has any thoughts about it.  Thanks.

Comment: This is bizarre! Is this Matlab, or Octave - since you tagged as 'both'? What version / what platform?

Comment: I also thought it was weird.  I tried both Matlab and Octave.  Octave version 3.2.4 and Matlab 7.13.0.564 both produce the same output.  Both on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I'm going to try this when I have a second…

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed a bit of a surprise that Matlab's syntax allows this. I don't know why this is allowed. One reason might be to allow for-loops on one line:

```
>> for i=1:3 disp(i);end
     1
     2
     3
```

But interestingly, removing the space is not allowed:

```
>> for i=1:3disp(i);end
 for i=1:3disp(i);end
        |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

This reason for this is probably that a number followed by `d` is another way of writing a floating point number (`3d10 == 3e10`), so the parser/tokenizer initially thinks you define a number, but then gets confused when it sees the `i`. Daniel's example with `fprintf` does work, since a number followed by an `f` is not a valid number, so the tokenizer understands that you started a new token.

I guess that many years ago (>30?), when they defined matlab's syntax, they did not foresee that this could introduce this kind of hard-to-spot problems. I guess matlab was originally written by engineers for engineers, and not by someone who knows how to design a general purpose programming language. Other languages like C or Python use punctuation to separate loop conditions from loop body, so there is no ambiguity. I don't know if it is still possible to correct Matlab's syntax, since it might break old code that relies on the current behavior.

At least, if you use a recent version of Matlab, the editor [warns for various problems](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-code-for-errors-and-warnings.html) in your code. Paying attention to the small red dashes in the right hand border could have saved you a few hours of debugging time (but maybe you were using octave). I try to make it a habit to fix all the warnings it indicates. For your code, it shows the following:

[image: editor Screenshot]

Comment: Reading this warning, it seems that this behaviour was never intended.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to

```
a = zeros(3);
for i=1:1
    size(a,2)
    i
end
```

There are some places where everyone would use newline or white space, but the parser itself does not require.

A minimal loop:

```
for i=1:3fprintf('%d',i),end
```

but I recommend to use at least a comma seperated version, everything else is horrible to read:

```
for i=1:3,fprintf('%d',i),end
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  Yes.  I realize that my code is equivalent to what you posted (if you re-read the question, I even posted that).  My question was *why* the Matlab designers would make the design decision that you wouldn't (at least) need a whitespace between the end of the range statement and the next statement.  Is there some construction that it's supposed to make easier or some ambiguity that they could not otherwise resolve?